# How can I know if a command works with pipe?

Tags: pipe, docker

I saw this command:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.State.Running}}' $(docker ps -lq)
```

and this:

```
docker ps -l -q|while read cid b; do docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Running }}' $cid; done;
```

My question is why it cannot be written as:

```
docker ps -l -q|docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}'
```

If that was because `docker inspect` does not work with pipe, how can I know which command can and which cannot?

Answer (score 2):

Pipe takes the output of the first program and passes it into the next program. In a sense, it pretends to be a user typing input into the second program in a terminal. So, if you can run the program and type in (for example) a list of files to operate on while the program is running, then you can do the same thing with a pipe.

You may see hints to what can be done using pipes in a program's manual. For instance, `man wget` mentions the `-i` argument, and that `-i -` will read files from standard input, also called STDIN. So you could `cat list-of-links.txt | wget -i -`, or more effectively `wget -i - < list-of-links.txt`.

Comment: A caveat to this is that _some_ programs acts _differently_ when the input comes from or goes to a pipe, compared from when connected to a terminal.